# char* func_name VS char *func_name (what are the differences)

Tags: c, pointers, return, return-type

What are the differences between a char pointer function and a pointer function?

```
char *get_next_line(int fd)
{
    static char *str;
    char        *line;

    if (fd <= 0 || BUFFER_SIZE <= 0)
        return (0);
    
    
}
```

and

```
char* get_next_line(int fd)
{
    static char *str;
    char        *line;

    if (fd <= 0 || BUFFER_SIZE <= 0)
        return (0);
    
    
}
```

Comment: The difference is the style. Nothing more, nothing less. There's also no difference between those two, and `char * get_next_line(int fd)`. C is in many parts agnostic of white-space. You could have tabs, newlines, spaces and any other valid white-space character in between, how many of them you like, and mix and match.

Comment: For the most part, spaces are not significant between tokens in C.

Comment: It's a little like the difference between "I'd have" and "I would've". :-)